# Joint moments like $\tau(XYXYXY)$ in terms of individual moments of free variables $X,Y$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, free-probability

Terry Tao [RMT book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf) has the following formula for joint moment of freely independent random variables $X,Y$ in Section 2.5

$$\tau(XYXY)=\tau(X)^2\tau(Y^2)+\tau(X^2)\tau(Y)^2-\tau(X)^2\tau(Y)^2$$

Exercise 2.5.17 then asks to prove that this is possible for any joint moment. Is there an easy to describe algorithm for actually constructing such formulas? IE, how would I get $\tau(XYXYXY)$?

I'm looking for procedure I can implement in Mathematica to build a "free probability" version of trace formula table like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865899/why-is-aataataataat-larger-than-aaaaatatatat-for-gaussian-a)

Comment: I wonder whether the community will some day recognize a subject called "random matrix theory" that somehow includes the study of Wishart matrices. Many books like the cited one by Terrence Tao never mention those, but I wonder whether, among those not belonging to the present-day random matrix community that consumes lots of things like that book, Wishart matrices my be the most well known random matrices.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The eigenvalues of Wishart matrices are the squares of the eigenvalues of  the block matrix that has X in its upper right corner, X^T in the lower left corner, and 0 elsewhere. As such, they are nothing but what is called "Generalized Wigner matrices". Much of the modern theory (including local laws, universality, etc) applies to generalized Wigner matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Such "concrete" formulas are addressed in Section 3.4. of my memoir [Combinatorial Theory of the Free Product with Amalgamation and Operator-Valued Free Probability Theory](https://rolandspeicher.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/memoirs.pdf). This is in the more general operator-valued context, where the calculations involve nestings of the moments, but of course the same formula is true in the usual scalar-valued case, where everything just factorizes into products. Whether those formulas allow an easy implementation in Mathematica, I don't know, as one has to sum over non-crossing partitions and the appearing coefficients have to be calculated in terms of the Moebius functions (and are, according to Proposition 3.4.2, given by products of signed Catalan numbers).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Wondering if there's a much simpler process for the special case when all individual moments =1

Comment: If all moments of X are equal to 1, then X is just the constant 1, so all mixed moments become trivial.

Comment: Oh right, I meant to ask if there's a much simpler answer for the case of all random variables being independent copies of the same random variable: $d\to \infty$ limit of $d\times d$  Gaussian matrix with $1/\sqrt{d}$ normalization

Comment: The limit of independent GUE matrices are free semicircular elements. For the calculation in this case, see [my book with Nica] (https://rolandspeicher.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/nica-speicher-book.pdf), Example 14.6. (2)

Answer (score 3):

Given a collection of free random variables $X_i $, to evaluate a trace of the form
$$
\tau [ f_1 (X_{i_1 } ) f_2 (X_{i_2 } ) \ldots f_n (X_{i_n } ) ]
$$
where $i_{j+1} \neq i_{j} $, consider the vanishing (by freeness) trace
$$
\tau [ (f_1 (X_{i_1 } ) - \tau [f_1 (X_{i_1 }])\
(f_2 (X_{i_2 } ) - \tau [f_2 (X_{i_2 }]) \ldots
(f_n (X_{i_n } ) - \tau [f_n (X_{i_n }]) ] = 0
$$
Multiplying this out, one can express the trace of a product of $n$ terms by traces of products of $(n-1)$, $(n-2)$, etc., terms, until the expression is reduced to one containing only individual moments.

Thus (using also cyclicity of the trace),
\begin{eqnarray}
\tau [XYXY] &=& 2\tau [X] \tau [X Y^2 ] +2\tau [Y] \tau[X^2 Y]
-4\tau [X] \tau [Y] \tau [XY] \\
& & {}-(\tau[X])^2 \tau [Y^2 ]
-(\tau[Y])^2 \tau [X^2 ]+4(\tau[X])^2 (\tau[Y])^2 \\
& & {}-(\tau[X])^2 (\tau[Y])^2 \\
&=& (\tau [X])^2 \tau [Y^2 ] + (\tau [Y])^2 \tau [X^2 ]
-(\tau [X])^2 (\tau [Y])^2
\end{eqnarray}
as noted in the OP, and similarly,
\begin{eqnarray}
\tau [XYXYXY] &=& 3\tau [X] \tau [XYXY^2] + 3\tau [Y] \tau [X^2 YXY]
-6\tau [X] \tau [Y] \tau [XYXY] \\
& & {}-3(\tau [X])^2 \tau [XY^3]-3\tau [X] \tau [Y] \tau [X^2 Y^2]
-3(\tau [Y])^2 \tau [X^3 Y] \\
& & {}+9(\tau [X])^2 \tau [Y] \tau [XY^2] + 9\tau [X] (\tau [Y])^2 \tau [X^2 Y]
+(\tau [X])^3 \tau [Y^3] \\
& & {}+(\tau [Y])^3 \tau [X^3] -9(\tau [X])^2 (\tau [Y])^2 \tau [XY]
-3(\tau [X])^3 \tau [Y] \tau [Y^2] \\
& & {}- 3\tau [X] (\tau [Y])^3 \tau [X^2] +6(\tau [X])^3 (\tau [Y])^3
-(\tau [X])^3 (\tau [Y])^3
\end{eqnarray}
To evaluate this, we need
\begin{eqnarray}
\tau [XYXY^2 ] &=& 2\tau [X] \tau [XY^3] + \tau [Y] \tau [X^2 Y^2]
+\tau [Y^2 ] \tau [X^2 Y] -2\tau [X] \tau [Y] \tau [XY^2] \\
& & {}- (\tau [X])^2 \tau [Y^3] -2\tau [X] \tau [Y^2 ] \tau [XY]
- \tau [Y] \tau [Y^2 ] \tau [X^2 ] \\
& & {}+4(\tau [X])^2 \tau [Y] \tau [Y^2 ]
-(\tau [X])^2 \tau [Y] \tau [Y^2 ] \\
&=& (\tau [X])^2 \tau [Y^3] + \tau [Y] \tau [Y^2 ] \tau [X^2 ]
-(\tau [X])^2 \tau [Y] \tau [Y^2 ]
\end{eqnarray}
Inserting this, as well as the expression with $X$ and $Y$ exchanged, and the previous result for $\tau [XYXY]$, we end up with
\begin{eqnarray}
\tau [XYXYXY] &=& 3\tau [X] \tau [Y] \tau [X^2 ] \tau [Y^2 ]
+(\tau [X])^3 \tau [Y^3] +(\tau [Y])^3 \tau [X^3] \\
& & {} -3(\tau [X])^3 \tau [Y] \tau [Y^2] -3(\tau [Y])^3 \tau [X] \tau [X^2]
+2(\tau [X])^3 (\tau [Y])^3
\end{eqnarray}
This seems feasible to automate (I'd be surprised if it hasn't been, but I don't know where to look).